# AVD на AMD с WINDOWS10 pro

Tags: эмулятор, amd, avd

В Android SDK включил Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (Installer).
С правами администратора запустил в Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver файл Silent_install.bat, но вместо успешной установки вижу это:

[SC] ControlService: ошибка: 1062:
Служба не запущена.
[SC] DeleteService: успех
[SC] StartService СБОЙ с ошибкой 4294967201.

Какой службы может не хватать?

Все сделал как в инструкции на 
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/12/emulator-29211-and-amd-hypervisor-12-to.html.

ОС - Win10 Pro.
Проц - AMD Ryzen 5 3500U.
В биосе виртуализация включена.
Помогите нубу стать на путь истинный)

Comment: Это вся ошибка?

Comment: Да, вся ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Технологии Hyper-V и платформа Windows Hypervisor +песочница должны быть ОТКЛЮЧЕНЫ, а вы их включаете.

Answer (score 0):

Точно такая же ошибка, точно такой же процессор. Мне потребовалась неделя, чтобы решить ее. Вам понадобится ваша Винда на флешке с записанным образом или диске. Загрузитесь в Биосе с нее, нажмите "Далее" в установке системы, а после нажмите снизу слева "Восстановление системы", "Поиск неиправностей", "Восстановление при загрузке". Если после этого шага пишет, что не удалось восстановить систему, идем дальше. "Дополнительные параметры", "Командная строка". Здесь вводите Diskpart и затем list volume. По размеру посмотрите, какой принадлежит диску с Виндой. Затем введите Exit. Снова в командой строке bcdboot X: \Windows, где Х - ваш диск с  Виндой. Exit, продолжить. Надеюсь, что помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Ты должен отключить Hyper-V, платформу виртуализации Windows, и песочницу виртуализации windows все их можно найти во Включение и Отключение компонентов Windows.
в настройках Bios ты должен в OS settings в предпоследнем или последнем пункте должен включить. "ВКЛЮЧИТЬ" SVM Mode, после чего можешь запускать установку все должно установиться. Если не установится, смотреть какие у тебя программы используют виртуализацию и отключать их. Например антивирусы или любые другие программы использующие виртуализацию

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).